# How to put & symbol in the Text property of TextBlock in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I need to the display the Text which is having the & symbol in the TextBlock... Is there any way to display in xaml...  Even i write the Text with the & symbol in the Text property of TextBlock.. It displays an error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you should try using `&amp;` which should show up as `&`

and maybe you can also achieve the same using CDATA `<![CDATA[&]]>`

[Special Characters in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It must be an encoding issue with xaml,  yoou could use html encoded string to print some special characters there.

for ampersand,  you coudld use `&amp;`. Hope this helps.